# Скролл элемента при наведении на fixed элемент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

При наведении на header, скролл не работает из-за фиксированого отображения, что вполне логично, но он должен всегда оставаться на месте, а страница скроллиться. Помогите найти решение

Чтобы было удобнее [я сделал пример на Code pen](https://codepen.io/LazyJoe/pen/oPKoxP/)

```js
var nav = $(".header");
var navList = $("ul.nav")
$('.container').on('scroll', function() {
  var top = $('.container').scrollTop();
  if (top > 150) {
    nav.css({
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
      height: '5vh'
    });
    navList.css({
      paddingTop: '0.2vh'
    });
  } else if (top <= 150) {
    nav.css({
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(223, 0 ,79, 1)',
      height: '20vh'
    });
    navList.css({
      paddingTop: '1vh'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  background: #000;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.header {
  background-color: rgba(223, 0, 79, 1);
  position: fixed;
  height: 20vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 30px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Baumans;
}

ul.nav {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3vh;
  line-height: 3vh!important;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 1vh;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  margin-block-start: 0px;
}

ul.nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 1.5vw;
  font-size: 3vh;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.nav li.is-active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 7px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

ul.nav li.is-active a {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

ul.nav li a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: neon-nav 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon-nav 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon-nav 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

@keyframes neon-nav {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #ff00e4, 0 0 70px #ff00e4, 0 0 80px #ff00e4, 0 0 100px #ff00e4, 0 0 150px #ff00e4;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #ff00e4, 0 0 35px #ff00e4, 0 0 40px #ff00e4, 0 0 50px #ff00e4, 0 0 75px #ff00e4;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header" id="header" style="#header{display: grid;}">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #2b2b2b 0%, #2b2b2b 10%, #222222 0%, #222222 50%) 0 / 15px 15px; height:1000vw; width: 10vw"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не ломайте код и не злоупотребляйте скриптами там, где это не критично. Добавьте в стилях:

- в `.header` - `pointer-events: none;`
- в `ul.nav li a` - `pointer-events: all;`

Всё.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так пойдет?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div id="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>

</div>

<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```